# How to reformat original data and then render a nested JSON request in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users
end
```

Which returns a json response like (in reality I have like 20 different attributes, this is just a subset):

```
 {“id”:1, “name”:”John”, "city": "New York"}, 
 {“id”:2, “name”:”Dave”, "city": "Chicago"}, 
 {“id”:3, “name”:”Peter”, "city": "Beijing"}
```

However I want the response to be more like this:

```
{“id”:1, “name”{"name”,"John”, "id":1}, "city": "New York"}, 
{“id”:2, “name”{"name”,"Dave”, "id":2}, "city": "Chicago"}, 
{“id”:3, “name”{"name”,"Peter”, "id":3}, "city": "Beijing"}
```

So that when I iterate through the request I can access attributes like this:

```
name.id         #will print 1
name.name       #will print “John”
city            #will print "New York"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just type it in brackets:

```
@users = User.all
render json: @users.map{ |k| {name: {name: k.name, id: k.id}, city: k.city} }
```

Comment: sorry should have been more specific. I updated the details of the questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry to do this again but I wasn't specific enough last time either. I should have mentioned that I was returning more than one object to be passed to json. Question updated once again.

Comment: Works! Thanks so much for your help/ patience!

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity#example

Some of the cool things are, that you can create different model definitions of whatever fields you need and you can nest any variations of these.
So for a slightly different example (Users with nested address objects):

In the models:

```
class User < Grape::Entity
  expose :name
end

class UserSimpleWithAddress < User
  expose :address, using: API::Entities::AddressSimple
end

class AddressSimple < Grape::Entity
  expose :zip
  expose :city
end
```

Rendering:

```
UserSimpleWithAddress.represent(@users).to_json
```

This is very handy when your models/needs get more complex by time.